# Identifying non-overlapping values between factors in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, overlap, iris-dataset

I would like to identify all non-overlapping values between groups (factors) in a dataframe. Let's use `iris` to illustrate. The `iris` dataset has measurements of sepal length, sepal width, petal length, and petal width for three plant species (*setosa*, *versicolor*, and *virginica*). All three species overlap in measurements of sepal length and width. In measurements of both petal length and width, *setosa* doesn't overlap with both *versicolor* and *virginica*.

What I want can be easily visualized manually using a variety of functions such as range values or scatter plots:

```
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, INDEX = iris$Species, FUN = range)
tapply(iris$Sepal.Width, INDEX = iris$Species, FUN = range)
tapply(iris$Petal.Length, INDEX = iris$Species, FUN = range)
tapply(iris$Petal.Width, INDEX = iris$Species, FUN = range)

# or

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Petal.Width)) + geom_point()
```

But it's impractical to do this manually for large datasets, so I'd like to write a function that identifies non-overlapping values between factors in dataframes like `iris`. The output could be a list of matrices with TRUE or FALSE (indicating non-overlap and overlap, respectively), one for each variable in the dataset. For example, the output for `iris` would be a list of 4 matrices:

```
$1.Sepal.Length
            setosa   versicolor   virginica
setosa      NA       FALSE        FALSE   
versicolor  FALSE    NA           FALSE   
virginica   FALSE    FALSE        NA   

$2.Sepal.Width
            setosa   versicolor   virginica
setosa      NA       FALSE        FALSE   
versicolor  FALSE    NA           FALSE   
virginica   FALSE    FALSE        NA   

$3.Petal.Length
            setosa   versicolor   virginica
setosa      NA       TRUE         TRUE   
versicolor  TRUE     NA           FALSE   
virginica   TRUE     FALSE        NA   

$4.Petal.Width
            setosa   versicolor   virginica
setosa      NA       TRUE         TRUE   
versicolor  TRUE     NA           FALSE   
virginica   TRUE     FALSE        NA
```

I accept suggestions of different outputs, as long as they identify all non-overlapping values.

Answer (score 3):

this is one possible solution within the `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)

# build custom function
my_fun <- function(x){
    # build tibble from input data (colum with metric) and Species vector from iris
    myDf <- dplyr::tibble(Species = as.character(iris$Species), Vals = as.numeric(x)) %>%
        # find min and max value per species
        dplyr::group_by(Species) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(mini = min(Vals), maxi = max(Vals)) 

    ret <- myDf %>%
        # build full join from data
        dplyr::full_join(myDf, by = character(), suffix = c("_1", "_2")) %>% 
        # convert operation to row wise
        dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
        # if species are the same generate NA else check if between  - I do negate here as if they are overlapping you want it to be FALSE
        dplyr::mutate(res = ifelse(Species_1 == Species_2, NA, !(dplyr::between(mini_1, mini_2, maxi_2) | dplyr::between(maxi_1, mini_2, maxi_2) | between(mini_2, mini_1, maxi_1) | dplyr::between(maxi_2, mini_1, maxi_1) ))) %>%
        # make tibble wide to get the wanted layout
        tidyr::pivot_wider(-c(mini_1, maxi_1, mini_2, maxi_2), names_from = Species_2, values_from = res) %>%
        # need it to be able to set row names
        as.data.frame()

    # set row names from column
    row.names(ret) <- ret$Species_1
    # remove column used to name rows
    ret$Species_1 <- NULL
    return(ret)
}

purrr::map(iris[, 1:4], ~my_fun(.x))

$Sepal.Length
           setosa versicolor virginica
setosa         NA      FALSE     FALSE
versicolor  FALSE         NA     FALSE
virginica   FALSE      FALSE        NA

$Sepal.Width
           setosa versicolor virginica
setosa         NA      FALSE     FALSE
versicolor  FALSE         NA     FALSE
virginica   FALSE      FALSE        NA

$Petal.Length
           setosa versicolor virginica
setosa         NA       TRUE      TRUE
versicolor   TRUE         NA     FALSE
virginica    TRUE      FALSE        NA

$Petal.Width
           setosa versicolor virginica
setosa         NA       TRUE      TRUE
versicolor   TRUE         NA     FALSE
virginica    TRUE      FALSE        NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I don't understand the `tidyverse` syntax, and so I'd prefer to do this work using the R base package. But your suggestion may resolve my problem for now. I tried to run your code, but it returned the following error in the last line: `Error in tidyr::pivot_wider(-c(mini_1, maxi_1, mini_2, maxi_2), names_from = Species_2,  : object 'mini_1' not found`

Comment: @goshawk there was a pipe (%>%) missing in my code... I just editted the answer accordingly and it should work... concercing a base R solution I will have to let you wait as I am very used to the tidyverse for data wrangling but not so much with base R though...

Comment: many thanks! This will work for now. I'll try to figure out how to write this function using base R just to understand more fully what the code is doing.

Comment: there's just one more problem: when running the code in datasets that contain `NA` values, the output will have `NA` in the entire row and column for that species that contain `NA` values. How could I resolve this? That is, I want the code to "ignore" NA values when calculating ranges.

Comment: Resolved - just use `na.rm = TRUE` within `min(Vals)` and `max(Vals)`